# Trying to get my script to send emails to the specified addresses in a textarea

Tags: php, email, textarea

I'm trying to create a very simple mailform. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <h2>Email Verzenden</h2>
        <script language = "Javascript">
        function explodeArray(emailID,delimiter) {
            tempArray=new Array(1);
            var Count=0;
            var tempString=new String(emailID);

            while (tempString.indexOf(delimiter)>0) {
                tempArray[Count]=tempString.substr(0,tempString.indexOf(delimiter));
                tempString=tempString.substr(tempString.indexOf(delimiter)+1,tempString.length-tempString.indexOf(delimiter)+1);
                Count=Count+1
                }

            tempArray[Count]=tempString.replace("\r","");
            return tempArray;
        } 

          function checkEmail(hallo) {
            if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(hallo)){
            return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
          function validate(){
            var emailID=document.form.email;
            var delimiter="\n";
            var emailArray=explodeArray(emailID.value,delimiter);
            var textID=document.form.text;
            var length = emailArray.length,
            element = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                emailVar = emailArray[i];

                if (emailVar==null){
                alert("Email-adres bestaat niet")
                emailID.focus()
                return false
                }               
                if (emailVar==""){
                alert("Email-adres veld is leeg")
                emailID.focus()
                return false
                }
                if (checkEmail(emailVar)==false){
                emailVar.value=""
                alert("Ongeldig E-mail adres");
                emailVar.focus()
                return false
                }
            }   
                if ((textID.value==null)||(textID.value==""))
                {
                alert("E-mail textveld is leeg")
                textID.focus()
                return false
                }
            return true
          }
        </script>
        <form name="form" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
        <pre>
            Vul hier de/het E-mail adres(sen) in
            <textarea name="email" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br>
            Typ hier de E-mail
            <textarea name="text" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </pre>
</form>
</html>
```

as you can see, there are 2 textareas. In the upper one, you're supposed to put down email addresses *underneath* eachother, and in the bottom one you're supposed to write the actual email. I already got my script to check if the email addresses are valid, and if the actual email actually has any input and whatnot, but I am clueless as to how to how implement any PHP code in order to actually send the e-mail to all the addresses filled in in the top textarea. Could anybody help me?

Comment: foreach loop and mail() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="yourscript.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
your textareas here
</form>
```

make yourscript.php.

```
<?
if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['email') && isset($_POST['text'])) {
 $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['email']);

 foreach($emails as $email) {
  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    mail($email, 'Subject', $_POST['text']);
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = explode("\n", $_POST['email']);
if (!empty($emails)) {
    foreach($emails as $email) {
        mail($email, 'My Subject', $_POST['text']);
    }
}
```